# How to customise android GridView Text?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

I'm working on a project and i have been struggling to customising the grid view text . I searched on different websites but I couldn't find an example on how to customise the text only .

I want to be able to add spacing, change the colour and maybe change the backgrounds of the rows.
If somebody has a tutorial or has a code that works I would be so thankful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share your code on how you are adding data to your GridView?

Answer (score 0):

Do a single Item Layout, and a grid layout, then on your adapter, inflate item layout for each intem, so they will stick into the grid layout.

This way you can edit the single item layout, and make it look as you want.

I'll Give You An Example On C#, But Easily You Can Use It On Java.

//Grid Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="400dp"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#444444" />
```

//Item Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#88FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

//On Your Grid Adapter Class

```
// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View grid;

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context
            .GetSystemService (Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        grid = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.gridItem, null);
    }
    else    {

        grid = (View) convertView;
    }

    ImageView image = (ImageView)grid.FindViewById (Resource.Id.image);
    TextView name= (TextView)grid.FindViewById (Resource.Id.name);

    image.SetImageBitmap(DecodeSampledBitmap ("Image Path", Width, Height));
    name.Text = "Text You Want";

    return grid;
}
```